# Unable to find the path PostgreSQLContainer testContainers

Tags: java, postgresql, testcontainers

I am unable to find my resource map when using [Test Containers](https://www.testcontainers.org), in Postgres version.
I am trying something like it:

```
     private static PostgreSQLContainer postgresqlContainer = new PostgreSQLContainer("postgres")
            .withDatabaseName(DATABASE_NAME)
            .withUsername(USER)
            .withPassword(PASSWORD);

    @ClassRule
    @BeforeAll
    public static void initContainer() {
        postgresqlContainer.withExposedPorts(5432);

        postgresqlContainer.withClasspathResourceMapping("../../../../../../../create.sh",
                "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/00_create.sh",
                BindMode.READ_ONLY);
        postgresqlContainer.start();
}
```

However, I can't find the file. I even tried to include the script create.sh in the same directory, but it can't be found:

*java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Resource with path ../../../../../../../create.sh could not be found on any of these classloaders*

Project Structure

[image]

Anyone with the same issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usage of `withClasspathResourceMapping` is when you have a classpath set. In my case, I didn't have and this method doesn't work. As replacement, I tried with addFileSystemBind and worked just fine:

```
postgresqlContainer.addFileSystemBind(scriptsPath + File.separator + "create.sh",
                "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/00_create.sh",
                BindMode.READ_ONLY);
```

Answer (score 2):

`withClasspathResourceMapping` uses [ClassLoader#getResource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource(java.lang.String)).
The argument is not relative to your class. Instead, it uses current classpath.
In your case, it should work with:

```
withClasspathResourceMapping("/db/create.sh", "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/00_create.sh")
```